# Git - new local branch current commits on local master?

Tags: git

I made a commit on my local master by accident and am waiting for it to go through the code review process. I don't want to lose that change. However, I want to work on other things in the meantime. When I try to checkout a new branch, my newest commit on my master branch is brought along for the ride too.

How can I get a fresh local branch that mirrors the state of the origin master without the recent commit on my local master?

Comment: Did you do **git commit** or **git add** ? Once you do git commit and checkout to any other branch, the current changes wont reflected in the newly loaded branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a branch—however you create it—you pick some *existing* commit out of your repository for that branch name to identify, so all you have to do is pick the right commit.

Think of commits as solid nodes full of stuff (data and metadata), connected by arrows.  It's a little hard to draw the arrows very well but we can do it kind of like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where each uppercase letter stands in for the actual hash ID of some actual commit.  (You'll see these big ugly hash IDs in `git log` output, for instance.)  The arrow is part of the commit's metadata: each commit stores the raw hash ID of its parent.  The arrows therefore all point *backwards*.

If you have some branching going on, it looks more like this:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I
```

Note that the end-most commits have an arrow coming *out* of them, but no arrow to let you *find* them.  Commit hash IDs look random, though, so we *need* arrows to find them.  That's what branch names are!

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- develop
```

To get there from here:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

you just need to draw `master` on a higher line (just for drawing purposes) and then make a name `develop` that points to existing commit `G`:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G   <-- develop
```

You can now `git checkout develop`, do stuff, and make a new commit.  Making a *new* commit makes it so that it points back to the current commit, and then updates the *current branch name* to point to the new commit.  So:

```
<make branch name "develop" identifying commit G>
git checkout develop
... develop and commit ...
```

and you have:

```
          H   <-- master
         /
...--F--G
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The `(HEAD)` just shows *which* is the current branch, here.

The hard part is finding the hash ID of `G`, but it's not that hard: `git log` tells you.  Then you can do:

```
git branch develop <hash>
```

Or, you can use special syntax: `master~1` means *find the commit to which the name `master` points, then step back one parent.*  So:

```
git branch develop master~1
```

does the right thing: finds `H`, counts back 1 to `G`, and creates the name `develop`.

Finally, you can combine the *make new branch name* and *check out name* operation in one:

```
git checkout -b develop master~1
```

which is pretty convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your master branch with the upstream master branch

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
```

please note that using reset --hard will cause your uncommitted changes to be lost, do a soft reset if you want to keep the uncommited changes